# change a charts border area color

Tags: python, matplotlib, pandas

Is it possible to set the area outside of the chart to the black color? I have the chart 
area set to black but the outside area has a grey color. Can i change this to black and maybe set the axis color to white if they are not visible?

I make a chart like this:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

test = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(100,3))

chart = test.cumsum().plot()
chart.set_axis_bgcolor('black')
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The border you're referring to can be modified using the `facecolor` attribute. The easiest way to modify this with your code would be to use:

```
plt.gcf().set_facecolor('white') # Or any color
```

Alternatively you can set it using a keyword argument if you create the figure manually.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

test = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(100,3))

bkgd_color='black'
text_color='white'

fig = plt.figure(facecolor=bkgd_color)

ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1)

chart = test.cumsum().plot(ax=ax)
chart.set_axis_bgcolor(bkgd_color)

# Modify objects to set colour to text_color

# Set the spines to be white.
for spine in ax.spines:
    ax.spines[spine].set_color(text_color)

# Set the ticks to be white
for axis in ('x', 'y'):
    ax.tick_params(axis=axis, color=text_color)

# Set the tick labels to be white
for tl in ax.get_yticklabels():
    tl.set_color(text_color)
for tl in ax.get_xticklabels():
    tl.set_color(text_color)

leg = ax.legend(loc='best') # Get the legend object

# Modify the legend text to be white
for t in leg.get_texts():
    t.set_color(text_color)

# Modify the legend to be black
frame = leg.get_frame()
frame.set_facecolor(bkgd_color)

plt.show()
```

[image: Plot]

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "set the axis color to white if they are not visible". Surely that will require the user to choose as how are you to decide what is "visible"?

Comment: I mean that now that i have both the backgrounds as black i cannot see the axis numbers. Sorry about the comment above it was incomplete and i entered it accidentaly.

Comment: So you wish to set both the face and axis colour to black and then modify the text colour so it is visible?

Comment: I have edited my answer and included an example output. The answer now converts all plotting objects (tick labels, legend, etc) so they are visible against a black background.

Answer (score 6):

Another solution which is less flexible than @Ffisegydd's answer but easier is that you can use style 'dark_background' predefined in pyplot module to achieve a similar effect. The code is:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# use style 'dark_background'
plt.style.use('dark_background')
test = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(100,3))

chart = test.cumsum().plot()
#chart.set_axis_bgcolor('black')

plt.show()
```

The above code produces [image: the following image].

#### P.S.

You can run `plt.style.available` to print a list of available styles, and have fun with these styles.

#### References

1. See [here](https://matplotlib.org/users/style_sheets.html) for a detailed explanations on how to use styles or compose custom styles and more...
2. Someone has made a [webpage](https://tonysyu.github.io/raw_content/matplotlib-style-gallery/gallery.html) which shows the display effect of all predefined styles. Pretty awesome!